# Proxy public URL to my local VM

Tags: networking, proxy

I have a local macbook behind a router in the company network that runs a Windows VM on parallels. I also have a linux VM on Linode.

I want to setup a public URL on my Linode that will forward all requests to my local macbook - specifically to an URL on my Windows VM.

How can this be done ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Squid or apache in reverse proxy mode

Yes this can be done, you will need to configure either [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) on your linux box.

Otherwise you can also do it using [apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) in reverse proxy mode:

> Apache can be configured in both a forward and reverse proxy (also
>   known as gateway) mode.
>
> An ordinary forward proxy is an intermediate server that sits between
>   the client and the origin server. In order to get content from the
>   origin server, the client sends a request to the proxy naming the
>   origin server as the target and the proxy then requests the content
>   from the origin server and returns it to the client. The client must
>   be specially configured to use the forward proxy to access other
>   sites.